# Can anyone find a way to solve this problem with O(logn) complexity?

Tags: optimization, data-structures, big-o

I am doing the leetcode daily problem (01/17/24), Climbing Stairs, I have finished the problem but with O(n) complexity. I was wondering if anyone could come up with a faster, more efficient solution to share.

Here is what I got with O(n) complexity:

```
public class Solution {
    public int ClimbStairs(int n) {
        //quick base case
        if (n <= 3 && n > 0) return n;

        //working total variables
        int total = 6, now = 2, next = 3;

        //for loop to calculate total
        for (int index = 3; index < n; index++) {
            total = now + next;
            now = next;
            next = total;
        }
        return total;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to find a recurrence relationship. If we want to know the number of possibilities for  (let's call that ), then we can consider two cases:

1. We take a short step first (1), and then the number of possibilities is <sub>−1</sub>
2. We take a long step first (2), and then the number of possibilities is <sub>−2</sub>

The sum of these is the solution:

= <sub>−1</sub> + <sub>−2</sub>

This is a Fibonacci recurrence relationship.

So the code could be something like this:

```java
class Solution {
    // Keep track of Fibonacci numbers across different runs:
    static ArrayList<Integer> fib = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 1));

    public int climbStairs(int n) {
        // If we don't have this Fibonacci number yet, extend what we have:
        for (int i = fib.size(); i <= n; i++) { 
            fib.add(fib.get(i - 2) + fib.get(i - 1));
        }
        // And now just return it:
        return fib.get(n);
    }
}
```

Of course, now you could look to the *constraints* of the challenge, and note that  will be at most 45. So then you could even precalculate the first 46 Fibonacci numbers and store them in a primitive array.

Answer (score 0):

This was already mentioned in another answer: counting the ways you can climb a staircase is given by the Fibonacci sequence. This is one of the [mathematical applications listed on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_sequence#Mathematics).

The way that problem is phrased on the site ("*you can either climb 1 or 2 steps.*") suggests the number of ways to climb "stairs" made of:

- 0 steps -> 0 (BTW, your code returns 6 here and I do not understand why).
- 1 step -> 1.
- 2 steps -> 2.

Conclusion: `climbstairs` differs from the Fibonacci sequence at the beginning, then the values returned have an offset of 1 with it (`climbstairs(n)` = `fibonacci(n+1)`) but this is about all we have to be careful about.

That same Wikipedia article, in an earlier section, describes how to calculate the [Fibonacci using arithmetics on matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_sequence#Matrix_form):
[image: Fibonacci numbers in a matrix]

Thanks to [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring), `M^n` can be calculated in `O(log(n))` steps.
By that, I do **not** mean this is the time complexity of the algorithm in the strict definition of the term: `O(log(n))` is valid only when we omit the complexity of applying `+`/`*` operators on very large integers, or rather consider they could be applied in `O(1)` time.
That is not the case: `fibonacci(n)` has `O(n)` digits and only a constant number of them can be calculated in O(1) time, so `fibonacci(n)` is bound to take at least `O(n)` time to calculate.
The multiplication of large integers happens to be slower than the addition but even considering that, applying `O(log(n))` multiplications/additions remains faster than applying `O(n)` additions.

In the C++ code below, note that the helper class `FiboMatrix` makes up for most of the code but it actually simplifies `climbStairs` quite a bit.
If you look carefully at the code for the class, especially `operator*`, you will notice some strange things. That is normal: `FiboMatrix` makes use of the structure of the matrices to optimize the memory usage (it is a 2x2 matrix made of only 3 numbers, since 1 of them is repeated) and the multiplication procedure is not a general-case matrix product: it is tailored for the particular structure they have (the top left element F<sub>n+1</sub> can be obtained by adding the other 2 elements).

```cpp
class Solution {
    class FiboMatrix {
    public:
        FiboMatrix()
            : vals{ 1, 1, 0 }
        {
        }
        FiboMatrix(std::array<unsigned long long, 2> values)
            : vals{ 0 }
        {
            vals[0] = values[1];
            vals[1] = values[0];
            vals[2] = values[1] - values[0];
        }
        unsigned long long* operator[](size_t r) const {
            return const_cast<unsigned long long*>(&vals[r]);
        }
        //Multiplication optimized for matrices structured for the Fibonacci sequence
        FiboMatrix operator * (FiboMatrix const& other) const {
            FiboMatrix result;
            for (size_t c = 0; c < 2; ++c) {
                result[1][c] = 0;
                for (size_t i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
                    result[1][c] += ((*this)[1][i]) * other[i][c];
            }
            result[0][0] = result[0][1] + result[1][1];
            return result;
        }

    private:
        std::array<unsigned long long, 3> vals;
    };
public:
    int climbStairs(int n) {
        if (n == 0) // special case
            return 0;
        //matrix = Fibonacci matrix
        //result = matrix rebuilt from the first 2 terms of the sequence (F(0) and F(1))
        FiboMatrix matrix, result({ 0,1 });
        
        for (; n > 0; n /= 2) { //Exponentiation by squaring
            if (n & 1)
                result = result * matrix;
            matrix = matrix * matrix;
        }
        return result[0][0];//climbStairs(n) = fibonacci(n + 1)
    }
};
```

If you want to learn more about the Fibonacci sequence and some of the ways to generalize it (e.g. what if you were able to climb 1, 2 **or 3** steps at a time?), I invite you to read [this MIT-licensed article](https://github.com/AtmoFX/bigint/blob/master/documentation/fibonacci.md) I wrote a while back.
There is some unexpected beauty stemming from the Fibonacci sequence, so I tried to make the article interesting.

This was done in the context of a [big integer library](https://github.com/AtmoFX/bigint); it is currently in the making but was made available nontheless and you should be able to make it run way beyond what 64-bit integers will allow.

Comment: I'm a third-year comp-sci student, so a lot of this is a little out of my league, but I think I understood it for the most part. Super interesting and definitely not something that I could've come up with at the time that I initially made the post. I appreciate your thorough response!

Comment: What part of it is out of your league?